# What effect will moving one light source closer to the screen have on the diffraction pattern of two coherent light sources?

Tags: visible-light, waves, laser, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

Say that you have two coherent light sources to begin with, each the same distance away from a screen, but then, you move one of the light sources closer to the screen by a fraction of the wavelength of the two coherent light sources. What effect will this have on the bandwidth, and the general look of the interference pattern on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely equivalent to tilting the projection screen relative the sources.

The *angular* pattern of minima nd maxima remains the same relative the line joining the two light sources, but those rays are now projecting onto a different surface.

Comment: Assuming  separation of sources << distance to screen?